# windows 10 install on new hard drive

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm helping a friend build a *new* PC. We want to install Windows 10 on it, I made a bootable of the Windows 10 Education iso but the install keeps failing around 30%. I suggested that it might be because there is no other version of Windows installed on the machine. Could this be the case? Because I have found conflicting information online.

Comment: any failure messages or codes? What happens at 30%?

Comment: says install failed and bring us back to the initial windows click to start install page (I'm not with the computer now and didn't write down the code). but basically I just want to know if you can do an windows 10 install from scratch or if you have to install windows 7 or 8 first then install windows 10.

Comment: 0x80070570 is the code, just had it sent to me

Comment: Probably a bad install image, remake the disc or usb drive again.

Comment: My first guess is some file on the installation media may be corrupt. You could also try redownloading the iso.

Comment: Yes you can do a clean install but you will need a purchased key, only way it is free is if it is upgraded from a previous version of windows and upgrade process must be started while booted into that previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to try and fix it. Here are a few:

---

**First try reformatting the HD and installing it again**

It could of been a small problem that caused this. When it brings you back to 'install now' screen install it again (Don't reboot). I had similar error and reinstalling it worked.

**Second reset BIOS**

Reset the BIOS settings on your PC but after you do so look to see if you have the settings

```
Execute Disable Bit
```

If you do, then **disable** it.

---

If all fails do what comments say above and re-download the ISO.

*Good Luck*

Comment: iso was the issue!